# css hide scroll bar in a popup nesting a page but not on the page itself

Tags: css, popup, scrollbar

I'm doing a wp site, using woocommerce, and a quick view plugin which gives you a popup small window preview of a page existing elsewhere.

What i'd like to do is to remove the scroll bar from the popup window but not from the real page.

Is it possible through css?

Using this in custom css, without success, so i'm thinking to hide the scroll bar from the page this popup shows, but then it'd disappear from the full page too obviously:

```
.xoo-qv-container {
height: 570px !important;
overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: maybe you're seeing the scroll bar of the page and not the popup

Comment: yea that's my doubt too, that's the reason of my question: is it possible to hide the scroll bar only when the page is shown in the popup?

Comment: is the popup using a frame? you could try disabling tha scroll bars for that instead.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use css, you can try accessing the body element as a child element of the popup.

Comment: Do you have any idea where I can find the body element in php files? i'm using a theme called storefront. Thanks

Comment: You can try `$('iframe').contents().find('body').css('overflow','hidden');`. The body element would probably be in the header file.